# Excel Multi select options in dropdown

Tags: vba, excel

In a spreadsheet, if I want to create a list of items for a dropdown for a user to select, is it possible to do a multi-select with checkboxes?

Something like

```
_ Item A
_ Item B
_ Item C
...
_ Item Z
```

and after selection

```
_ Item A
X Item B
...
X Item Z
```

and in another cell (or cell in other worksheet), have a comma separated list

```
B,Z (or 2, 26 for the values)
```

Comment: What do you mean by multi-select with checkboxes? Checkboxes are separate items that lets you do *multi select*. Why do you need to use Checkboxes instead of multi-select dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do multi-select.  You can use an ActiveX list box if configured properly.  A form control list box does multi-select but without checkboxes.  You can also use regular checkboxes.  Here's a good overview of all the available form controls: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-HA010237663.aspx#BMactivex_controls_on_the_control_toolb

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same requirement, additionally need to support unselect as well.
Hecen, I have posted a working solution of Spread-sheet with Multi drop-down with comma(,) separated values in spread sheet cell. I though of sharing here, as could be helpful to others.

1. Select values from drop-down values appended into cell with comma(,) separation.
2. Users would be able to do un-select by clicking again to selected value.
3. If users press delete on cell with values, it will work as un-select-all(reset).

Here is [stack-overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539722/multiselect-in-excel-using-macros-how-to-un-select-the-selection) of the question/solution.