# MultiSelect in Excel using Macros, how to un-select the Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create Macro enabled excelsheet with MultiSelect dropdown.

1. Users choose one of drop-down, then value appended into the Cell with Comma(,) Separation.
2. If user selects, already selected value again, then it should be removed from list.

I was able to achieve first part of it, by following code, but couldn't achieve second part.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
      If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
      Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
          If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
          Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
          Else:
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

How to achieve part #2? Please suggest.

Comment: does `If Target.Address = "$D" Then` actually return `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest similar like @displayname, but would do with for loop and replace else part of your code.

```
  Dim substrings() As String
    substrings = Split(Oldvalue, ", ")
    Target.Value = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
        If Not (substrings(i) = Newvalue) Then
          Target.Value = Target.Value & ", " & substrings(i)
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

you could substitute:

```
If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
    Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
```

with:

```
    If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
        Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
    Else
        Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, Newvalue, "") ' remove value from list
        If Right(Target.Value, 1) = "," Then 'if removed value was the last value of the list
            Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, Len(Target.Value) - 1) ' remove ending comma
        ElseIf Left(Target.Value, 1) = "," Then 'if removed value was the first value of the list
            Target.Value = Mid(Target.Value, 2) ' remove leading comma
        Else ' removed value was in the middle of the list
            Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ",,", "") ' remove double comma
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code based on @RedBoy and @yser9817739 and improved and fixed issues. I also added a check for copy/paste and Auto Fill.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sOldvalue As String
    Dim sNewvalue As String
    Dim substrings() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim bFound As Boolean: bFound = False
    Dim sUndoList As String

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    sUndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If Left(sUndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or sUndoList = "Auto Fill" Then GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            'Adding first item
            If Trim(Target.Value) = "" Then
                GoTo Exitsub
            Else
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                sNewvalue = Target.Value
                Application.Undo
                sOldvalue = Target.Value
                If Trim(sOldvalue) = "" Then
                    Target.Value = sNewvalue
                Else
                    substrings = Split(sOldvalue, ",")
                    For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
                        If Trim(substrings(i)) = Trim(sNewvalue) Then bFound = True
                    Next i
                    If Not bFound Then
                        Target.Value = sOldvalue & "," & sNewvalue
                    Else
                        Target.Value = ""
                        For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
                            If Not (Trim(substrings(i)) = Trim(sNewvalue)) And Len(Trim(substrings(i))) <> 0 Then
                                If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
                                    Target.Value = Trim(substrings(i))
                                Else
                                    Target.Value = Target.Value & "," & Trim(substrings(i))
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sOldvalue As String
Dim sNewvalue As String
Dim substrings() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim bFound As Boolean: bFound = False
Dim sUndoList As String

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub



sUndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(sUndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or sUndoList = "Auto Fill" Then GoTo Exitsub



If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else
        'Adding first item
        If Trim(Target.Value) = "" Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            sNewvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            sOldvalue = Target.Value
            If Trim(sOldvalue) = "" Then
                Target.Value = sNewvalue
            Else
                substrings = Split(sOldvalue, ",")
                For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
                    If Trim(substrings(i)) = Trim(sNewvalue) Then bFound = True
                Next i
                If Not bFound Then
                    Target.Value = sOldvalue & "," & sNewvalue
                Else
                    Target.Value = ""
                    For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
                        If Not (Trim(substrings(i)) = Trim(sNewvalue)) And Len(Trim(substrings(i))) <> 0 Then
                            If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
                                Target.Value = Trim(substrings(i))
                            Else
                                Target.Value = Target.Value & "," & Trim(substrings(i))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If



Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).